# R does not find function anno_simple() when creating a row annotation using ComplexHeatmap package

Tags: r, annotations, heatmap

I am trying to create an heatmap with a row annotation inclusive of p-values as reported in the example in the guide for the use of the ComplexHeatmap package (https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap-reference/book/heatmap-annotations.html#simple-annotation).

I tried to reproduce the example:

```
library(ComplexHeatmap)
library(circlize)  # colorRamp2 function

set.seed(123)
pvalue = 10^-runif(10, min = 0, max = 3)
is_sig = pvalue < 0.01
pch = rep("*", 10)
pch[!is_sig] = NA

# color mapping for -log10(pvalue)
pvalue_col_fun = colorRamp2(c(0, 2, 3), c("green", "white", "red"))
ha = HeatmapAnnotation(
   pvalue = anno_simple(-log10(pvalue), col = pvalue_col_fun, pch = pch),
   annotation_name_side = "left")
ht = Heatmap(matrix(rnorm(100), 10), name = "mat", top_annotation = ha)

# now we generate two legends, one for the p-value
# see how we define the legend for pvalue
lgd_pvalue = Legend(title = "p-value", col = pvalue_col_fun, at = c(0, 1, 2, 3),
   labels = c("1", "0.1", "0.01", "0.001"))

# and one for the significant p-values
lgd_sig = Legend(pch = "*", type = "points", labels = "< 0.01")

# these two self-defined legends are added to the plot by `annotation_legend_list`
draw(ht, annotation_legend_list = list(lgd_pvalue, lgd_sig))
```

but when I am creating the annotation `ha` I get the error

```
Error in anno_simple(-log10(pvalue), col = pvalue_col_fun, pch = pch) :
 could not find function "anno_simple"
```

likely showing a possible problem with the package.
The version of the ComplexHeatmap package I am running is 1.20.0.
The R version is 3.5.1.

Could you please help me solving this problem?

Thanks

Comment: hey it works for me.. might be too old version of R. I am on 3.6.1, ComplexHeatmap_2.0.0... install the new version ?

Comment: Works for me too. I'm using ComplexHeatmap version 2.3.2.